Probably old horror movie with a doctor from America travelling to a cursed or haunted place
I'm looking for a horror movie and all I remember is a scene. It's of a child in a hospital bed and all that's in the room (tan room) is the kid and the IV pole that the kid's hooked up to and then all of sudden, while the doctor has his back turned and is leaving the room, the kid's IV bag begins to fill up with blood.
The plot of the movie I think is like, a doctor from America travels to a desert area and the area is occupied by a lot of sick people but the area also turns out to be cursed or haunted.
Please help me find this movie, it's driving me crazy.

Any other details like when you watched it? What time period was the movie made? Language? Country?

The film you are thinking of is Exorcist: The beginning.
the scene is describing in a review on IMBD Quote below
"examples: the boy watches with blank expression as his elder brother is eaten by hyena's. he's put into a hospital bed after he develops a fever, he then develops legions. whilst in his fever, he opens his eyes and stares, then rolls his eyes up and falls unconscious again. his liquid feed fills with blood and he shakes uncontrollably. his bed shakes violently. but why? he's not even possessed.
"
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0204313/reviews-306
